# WPF Validation on a child control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl with a TextBox inside like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.CommonControls.Views.InPlaceEdit"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Name="parent"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Border Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <TextBox x:Name="ButtonEdit"
                Text="{Binding ElementName=parent,
                               Path=Value,
                               Mode=TwoWay,
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </TextBox >
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

Usage:

```
<controls:InPlaceEdit Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Height="25"
    Margin="5,0,0,5"
    Value="{Binding SelectedPatient.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Question is: how to move Validation errors to my TextBox? It's because all ValidationErrors are stored in my InPlaceEdit control, and not populated properly to TextBox.

(It's simplified view, but basically shows my problem. In my application I'm using ButtonEdit from DevExpress instead TextBox)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by removing Text binding from my child control and setting a binding to be exactly same as a parent:

```
this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this, ValueProperty);
    if (binding != null)
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(ButtonEdit, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEditBase.TextProperty, binding);
    }
};
```